# Enviar datos por url con jquery

Tags: jquery

Como se envian los datos por url en jquery?
tengo un ejemplo en js nativo y quiero pasarlo a jquery

```
        var f2=document.getElementById('fechaFinal').value;
        window.location.href='localhost/reporte.php?f2='+f2;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con

```
$(location).attr('href',URL_PAGINA_WEB);
```

Donde `location` corresponde a `window.location`

`href` es el atributo `href` y
`URL_PAGINA_WEB` vendira siendo `localhost/reporte.php?f2='+f2`

[Aquí](http://code.jc-mouse.net/posts/apuntes/199/redireccionar-pagina-web-con-jqu.html) puedes ver un poco mas como funciona todo

Comment: Genial muchas Gracias!

Comment: @matteo un placer, Si intentaste la respuesta y de verdad funcionó marca la respuesta como "aceptada" debajo de las valoraciones, para indicar que es la respuesta correcta

Answer (score 2):

puedes usar el metodo $.get();

```
var params = {
   param_1 : $("#input1_id").val(),
   param_2 : $("#input2_id").val(),
   ....
   param_n : $("#inputN_id").val()
};

$.get(URL, params, function(e){
    // algo que quieras hacer despues de enviar la petición.
});
```

Al final en la URL se concatenan los parámetros con &, y del lado del servidor los obtienes con el verbo $_GET, suerte!!.